# How to handle embedded composite key?

Tags: java, hibernate, composite-primary-key

I have a table called watchlist that consists of only two fields, symbol and name. The combination is unique. I'm getting hibernate error:

> "Repeated column in mapping for entity"

error and I can't figure out why.

I have created a WatchlistId class like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class WatchlistId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="symbol")
    private String symbol;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    WatchlistId() {     
    }

    WatchlistId(String symbol, String name) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
    }
//getters and setters
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
 
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
 
        WatchlistId that = (WatchlistId) o;
        return Objects.equals(symbol, that.symbol) && Objects.equals(name, that.name);
    }
 
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(symbol, name);
    }
```

The Watchlist class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "watchlist")
public class Watchlist {
    @EmbeddedId
    public WatchlistId watchlistId;
    
    private String symbol;
    private String name;
 
    public Watchlist() {      
    }
    
    public Watchlist(WatchlistId watchlistId, String symbol, String name) {
        this.watchlistId = watchlistId;
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public WatchlistId getWatchlistId() {
        return watchlistId;
    }
    public void setWatchlistId(WatchlistId watchlistId) {
        this.watchlistId = watchlistId;
    }
}
```

The repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface WatchlistRepository extends JpaRepository<Watchlist, WatchlistId>{
    @Query(value="select * from watchlist w where (name = :w.watchlistId.name)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Watchlist> getWatchlist(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query(value="insert into watchlist w (symbol,name) values (:watchlist.watchlistId.symbol,:watchlist.watchlistId.name)", nativeQuery = true)
    String addSymbolToWatchlist(@Param("watchlist") Watchlist watchlist);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `@Embeddable`, the fields from the embeddable class are automatically added to the table, so you get duplicates.

Thus, you need to remove `symbol` and `name` fields and use them from `WatchlistId` member:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "watchlist")
public class Watchlist {
    @EmbeddedId
    public WatchlistId watchlistId;
    
    public String getSymbol(){
        return watchlistId.getSymbol();
    }
    
    public String getName(){
        return watchlistId.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you cdalxndr.  That seemed to fix the error I described.  Now a new error: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List net.tekknow.moneymachine.repository.WatchlistRepository.getWatchlist(java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[name]' not found in annotated query 'select * from watchlist w where (name = :w.watchlistId.name)'!

Comment: @user3217883 You used `@Param("name")`, so the sql parameter name must be the same (`name`). Replace `:w.watchlistId.name` with `:name`.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Silly me.  Thanks so much!  I'm gradually getting this complicated stuff thanks to kind people like you.